# Mysql Data Import Using Ruby

Tags: mysql, ruby, mysqlimport

I am implementing csv file import from front end using ruby into mysql.
this is my controller code

```
    require 'csv'

       def csv_import 
         @parsed_file=CSV::Reader.parse(params[:dump][:file])
         n=0
         @parsed_file.each  do |row|
         c=CustomerInformation.new
         c.job_title=row[1]
         c.first_name=row[2]
         c.last_name=row[3]
         if c.save
            n=n+1
            GC.start if n%50==0
         end
         flash.now[:message]="CSV Import Successful,  #{n} new records added to data base"
       end
```

This is my front end code.

```
<pre>
<% form_for :dump, :url=>{:controller=>"customer_informations", :action=>"csv_import"}, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| -%>
 <table">
   <tr>
     <td>
      <label for="dump_file">
        Select a CSV File :
      </label>
     </td>
     <td >
       <%= f.file_field :file -%>
     </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td colspan='2'>
       <%= submit_tag 'Submit' -%>
     </td>
   </tr>
 </table>
<% end -%>
</pre>
```

Now what i want is , I have around 30 columns in DB , the csv will contain 30 column headings. Also, for a checkup, I shall ask one of the columns as input using textfield , so that makes 29 columns in the csv sheet. As per the option selected by the user , dose 29 columns gets attached with the selected entity from the text box.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you make the headers the same as the table columns, your code should be as simple as:

```
CSV::foreach(filename, :headers => true) do |row|
  Model.new(row.to_hash).save
end
```

Comment: so if i leave out any column in file, it will not insert the data in dat column in db.,??

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand that sentence at all.

Comment: i meant that i am having 30 columns in my database. if i make only 29 columns in my excel file with column headings , will it adjust itself and place the data as per the column header.?

Comment: Yes, the idea is to have the hash keys correspond to the field names.